# How to name a folder like the files that are copied into it?

Tags: batch-file, directory, filenames

I have a batch script that moves `.eps` and `.pdf` files into separate folder with `.eps` in `Highres`, and `.pdf` in `Lowres`. But I want to name the main folder as the file name.

For instance, if I am copying `Man.eps` and `Man.pdf`, the respective main folder name should be `Man` and inside that, `Man.eps` should be in `Highres` subfolder, and `Man.pdf` should be in `Lowres` subfolder.

Here is what I  have come so far:

```
@echo off & setlocal

> nul mkdir "%%~pA"
for %%F in (*.eps) do (
    > nul mkdir "%%~pA/HIGHRES"
    > nul move "%%F" "%%~pA/HIGHRES"
    for %%F in (*.pdf) do (
        > nul mkdir "%%~pA/LOWRES"
        > nul move "%%F" "%%~pA/LOWRES"
    )
)
```

It creates folder name with `%%~pA`, I just want the file name to be used as the folder name...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code. When using for to loop through a fileset, you should use `for /R`. Furthermore, `%%~pA` tries to get part of a variable named `%%A`, which you don't have. Also, you shouldn't forget to close your first for loop. Finally, you should use `~n` and `~nx` to get filename or filename+extension respectively.

Try this:

```
@echo off
for /R %%F in (*.eps) do (
    mkdir "%%~nF/HIGHRES"
    move "%%F" "%%~nF/HIGHRES/%%~nxF"
)
for /R %%F in (*.pdf) do (
    mkdir "%%~nF/LOWRES"
    move "%%F" "%%~nF/LOWRES/%%~nxF"
)
```

Comment: If you feel like my answer solved your problem you should mark it as correct by clicking the check to the left of it